# getting error: ./autogen.sh: no such file or directory

Tags: 16.04

all, I'm a Ubuntu new user, and I'm now using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. 
When I want to compile the ./autogen.sh, and I got an error that there is no such file or directory. But I have installed the autoconf, automake, autogen, etc already. I don't know why, can anyone tells me how to fix it, or what reason may cause this error? I searched may methods, but all failed... I'm now very very worried... Any help will be appreciated.

[Edited] So here is the solution. We don't need ./autogen.sh anymore. What I need is to install the protobuf-compiler binary package, because it is just a protoc error.  Thanks very much for the @steeldriver's help.

Comment: What do you mean by *"compile the ./autogen.sh"*? An autogen.sh file is a script that is sometimes provided by a source package and is specific to that package. What software are you trying to compile, and where did you get it?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Here is the thing. I want to run the simulation in http://www.yonch.com/wireless. Before that I need to setup the environment as the author tells. And I did follow the step (this is my first time to use linux OS). Many questions, and I tried to solve them by google. Then I need to setup the protocol, because I got such an error configure: error: Could not find protoc in the path, please install it or add to the path.

Comment: So I went to https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md to follow their step. Then I met this error that ./autogen.sh no file or directory. I don't know what I can do now, and I don't know how to fix it. Please help me ...

Comment: On Ubuntu systems, it's rarely necessary to dive down the rabbit-hole of compiling *dependencies* from source: have you tried simply installing `libprotobuf-dev` from the repository?

Comment: Yes, I tried. and it tells me that libprotobuf-dev as the newest version (2.6.1-1.3). But still cannot ./autogen.sh. And I also tried to use whereis autogen.sh, but only return the location of autogen.

Comment: I don't see anything in the [yonch libwireless and wireless-python](http://www.yonch.com/wireless) instructions that you linked saying to run `./autogen.sh` - just `autoreconf --install` followed by `../configure` from the `release` subdirectory

Comment: But ../configure from the release doesn't succeed, because it returns an error error: could not find protoc in the path, please install it or add it to the path. Some people said it's because the codes are from GitHub (no gmock), not whole release..

Comment: @JunchaoMa Please [edit] your question to include all these details you wrote in comments. It'll make it easier for other users to help.

Comment: @JunchaoMa the `protoc` error is nothing to do with autoconf - you probably just need to install the `protobuf-compiler` binary package.

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, thank you, there is no such error. Thank you very very much. But I get another error that gawk: symbol lookup error: gawk: undefined symbol: mpfr_z_sub; config.status: error: could nor create Makefile.  Every step makes me crazy...